# abp.io how to remove the Identity Server in Angular Template

Tags: angular, identityserver4, multi-tenant, abp

We would like to remove the Identity Server Integration from the ABP.IO Angular Project, and instead use the Microsoft Identity for the User Authentication and Authorization, Can anybody provides some guidelines to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

IdentityServer and Microsoft.Identity **are not** substitutes.

IdentityServer is an **OpenIdConnect implementation** and deals with authentication of devices.

Microsoft.Identity (AspnetIdentity) is a library that provides UI and datastore abstractions (UserStore, RoleStore etc) and basic implementations (UserManager, RoleManager, IdentityUser etc) so that you can use or override as your business needs.

It is important to know the difference.

I would suggest reading [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to understand the subject better since you need to use an **Authorization Server** (IdentityServer, Azure Active Directory etc.) for your API and SPA authentication.

### **TLDR**

**No**, you can't remove identityserver if you created a *separate (tiered) identityserver project*. You can always create non-tiered angular application so HttpApi hosts the authentication-server (identityserver) in it.